# Sublime Text - spell check but only certain file extensions

Tags: sublimetext2, markdown, sublimetext3, sublimetext, spell-checking

There's no point of enabling spell check for your html/js/css/c/php/py/etc files, but it can be very useful when you are writing in Markdown.

How to enable spell check only for only certain file extensions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can add a **syntax specific setting**:

1. Open a file with the syntax for which you want to enable spell-check (such as *markdown* in your case).
2. Open menu `Settings…` -> `Settings - Syntax Specific`.
3. This file should contain a JSON object. Add the key/value pair: `{ "spell_check": true }` (or false for the reverse effect).
4. Save and close this file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've updated the path for future readers.

Comment: I just added this for my `md` files. Do you know the `tmTheme` key for spelling errors?

Comment: I don't know it. I haven't seen any theme or color scheme that changes spelling errors underlined style.

Comment: from [sublime text forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/auto-spell-check-sublime-3/12930) **regarding sublime setting syntax :**
 If the file is not empty, at the top after the "{" add a new entry
 `"spell_check":true,`
 The comma is important

Comment: How does this work for only specific file types? This looks like it applies to all files.

Comment: @2540625 it works because there is a file for global preferences, and a different file for the preferences of every file-type/syntax-type (for example Markdown file-type preferences). You can set the value you need for the global preferences and override using the specific file-type. To change global preferences you can use the menu `Preferences>Settings`, and to change the Markdown preferences you can open a Markdown file, and then use the menu `Preferences>Setting-SYTNAX SPECIFIC`