# Cmd + S of TeX file in Sublime Text turns off spell check [MacOS]

Tags: sublimetext3

**Problem**

I have been experiencing this weird effect where every time I press `Cmd+s` to save a `.tex` file, the spell check gets disabled.

**I tried ...**

This bug is not there in other file types (tested on `.txt`, `.py`, `.bib`, `.nml`)

**Builds**

I use Sublime Text build `4143` on MacOS Monterey `12.6.3`. and I edit `.tex` files to build documents using the Sublime package called `LaTeXing` `1.4.0`.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986782/sublime-text-spell-check-but-only-certain-file-extensions?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The procedure in the link pointed out in the comments by @Parthis worked for me.

In short:

1. Open a `.tex` file (or whichever file you want to keep the spell check on).
2. Go to `Preferences` > `Settings - Syntax Specific`. This will open a settings file specific to `.tex`. Mine was blank with only `{` `}`.
3. Add `"spell_check": true` between the `{` `}`

Now my spellcheck is not affected by `Cmd+s` anymore!